# Python lxml how to post process XPath result again with XPath

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Unified Streaming Platform(version=1.7.8) -->
<MPD
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
        type="static"
        mediaPresentationDuration="PT1H43M36.832S"
        maxSegmentDuration="PT3S"
        minBufferTime="PT10S"
        profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011,urn:com:dashif:dash264">
    <Period>
        <BaseURL>dash/</BaseURL>
        <AdaptationSet group="1" contentType="audio" lang="tr" minBandwidth="157405" maxBandwidth="157405"
                       segmentAlignment="true" audioSamplingRate="48000" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2">
            <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2">
            </AudioChannelConfiguration>
            <Representation id="audio_tur=157405" bandwidth="157405">
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet group="2" contentType="video" lang="en" par="16:9" minBandwidth="501000" maxBandwidth="9001000"
                       minWidth="512" maxWidth="1920" minHeight="288" maxHeight="1080" segmentAlignment="true"
                       frameRate="25" mimeType="video/mp4" startWithSAP="1">
            <Representation id="video_eng=501000" bandwidth="501000" width="512" height="288" codecs="avc1.4D401E"
                            scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=851000" bandwidth="851000" width="640" height="360" codecs="avc1.4D401E"
                            scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=1302000" bandwidth="1302000" width="640" height="480" sar="4:3"
                            codecs="avc1.4D401F"
                            scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=2601000" bandwidth="2601000" width="1024" height="576" codecs="avc1.4D401F"
                            scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=2701000" bandwidth="2701000" width="1280" height="720" codecs="avc1.4D401F"
                            scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=3501000" bandwidth="3501000" width="1280" height="720" codecs="avc1.4D401F"
                            scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=6001000" bandwidth="6001000" width="1440" height="1080" sar="4:3"
                            codecs="avc1.4D4028" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=9001000" bandwidth="9001000" width="1920" height="1080" codecs="avc1.4D4028"
                            scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet
                group="2" contentType="video" lang="en" par="20:11" minBandwidth="1901000" maxBandwidth="1901000"
                minWidth="872" maxWidth="872" segmentAlignment="true" width="720" height="480" sar="40:33"
                frameRate="25" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401F" startWithSAP="1">
            <Representation id="video_eng=1901000" bandwidth="1901000" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

And run the following Python code on it:

```
from lxml import etree

file = "Data.xml"
namespaces = {'ns':'urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011'}

tree = etree.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

for r in root.xpath('//ns:AdaptationSet[@contentType="video"]',namespaces=namespaces):
    print etree.tostring(r)
    for bandwidth in r.xpath('//ns:Representation/@bandwidth',namespaces=namespaces):
        print bandwidth
```

My problem is now that the second loop is not using the result from the xpath before but again the complete tree! That's why the results include representations for audio as well. In detail it looks like the following:

```
<AdaptationSet xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" group="2" contentType="video" lang="en" par="16:9" minBandwidth="501000" maxBandwidth="9001000" minWidth="512" maxWidth="1920" minHeight="288" maxHeight="1080" segmentAlignment="true" frameRate="25" mimeType="video/mp4" startWithSAP="1">
            <Representation id="video_eng=501000" bandwidth="501000" width="512" height="288" codecs="avc1.4D401E" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=851000" bandwidth="851000" width="640" height="360" codecs="avc1.4D401E" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=1302000" bandwidth="1302000" width="640" height="480" sar="4:3" codecs="avc1.4D401F" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=2601000" bandwidth="2601000" width="1024" height="576" codecs="avc1.4D401F" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=2701000" bandwidth="2701000" width="1280" height="720" codecs="avc1.4D401F" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=3501000" bandwidth="3501000" width="1280" height="720" codecs="avc1.4D401F" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=6001000" bandwidth="6001000" width="1440" height="1080" sar="4:3" codecs="avc1.4D4028" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="video_eng=9001000" bandwidth="9001000" width="1920" height="1080" codecs="avc1.4D4028" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>

157405
501000
851000
1302000
2601000
2701000
3501000
6001000
9001000
1901000
<AdaptationSet xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" group="2" contentType="video" lang="en" par="20:11" minBandwidth="1901000" maxBandwidth="1901000" minWidth="872" maxWidth="872" segmentAlignment="true" width="720" height="480" sar="40:33" frameRate="25" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401F" startWithSAP="1">
            <Representation id="video_eng=1901000" bandwidth="1901000" scanType="progressive">
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>

157405
501000
851000
1302000
2601000
2701000
3501000
6001000
9001000
1901000
```

So even the right AdaptionSet's are found, for both iterations the complete tree is processed. I know I could build a XPath just getting the bandwith, but I need the AdaptionSet before and would love to use only the result from the first loop for the second. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to add `.` at the beginning of your XPath to make it *relative to* current context node, which in this case referenced by the variable `r` :

```
r.xpath('.//ns:Representation/@bandwidth',namespaces=namespaces)
```

This behavior is mentioned in the [XPath 1.0 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) as follow :

> - `//para` selects all the para descendants of the document root and thus selects all para elements in the same document as the context node
> - `.//para` selects the para element descendants of the context node

Comment: Note, even if you start at the node returned by the first XPath evaluation, you are still running it against the original tree (not against a copy). So for example `.//*[ancestor::Period]` will return true, because there is a Period element in the original tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try using relative xpath -

```
for bandwidth in r.xpath('.//ns:Representation/@bandwidth',namespaces=namespaces):
```

`.` would make the xpath start at the current element. If the `.` is not specified, as you observed, the xpath would query from the root node.